# What is a good OCR that can detect handwriting?

Tags: ocr

I need a library that can extract text from handwritten paper once I scan it. Normal Latin text.

It can be a free solution or even something I have to pay for, as long as it handles handwriting for block letters (not cursive).

Comment: When I worked with OCR it was tedious at best - You had to teach it and then it was limited to what it could understand. This was about 10yrs ago and I am also curious on how this has progressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an OCR program capable of recognising hand-written text well; it's not something that can be solved easily.

There are, however, strong commercial systems which are possible to train if the variancy isn't too great. For example, take a look at [ABBYY](http://www.abbyy.com).