# Recognize a number from an image

Tags: java, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, hough-transform

I'm trying to write an application to find the numbers inside an image and add them up.

How can I identify the written number in an image?

[image]

There are many boxes in the image I need to get the numbers in the left side and sum them to give total. How can I achieve this?

Edit: i did a java tesseract ocr on the image but i didnt get any correct results. how can i train it?

also

i did a edge detection i got this:

[image]

Comment: Are the rectangles containing *both* numbers always underneath each other?

Comment: What you are looking for is OCR. Did you google for existing OCR tools? As it turns out, google has one called tesseract with a JNI implementation called tessjeract. Check it out.

Comment: @npinti the rectangles are on the right of the paper distance will vary as there are questions in between. bt will be in a straight line.

Comment: @bot i tried tesseract on that image it just gave me 'S878', and im trying to do in java

Comment: @ChetanKinger Apparently the `tessjeract` project has now disappeared from the web :(

Answer (score 20):

You will most likely need to do the following:

1. Apply the [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) algorithm on the entire page, this should should yield a series of page sections.
2. For each section you get, apply it again. If the current section yielded 2 elements, then you should be dealing with a rectangle similar to the above.
3. Once that you are done, you can use an OCR to extract the numeric value.

In this case, I would recommend you take a look at [`JavaCV`](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) (OpenCV Java Wrapper) which should allow you to tackle the Hough Transform part. You would then need something akin to [`Tess4j`](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/) (Tesseract Java Wrapper) which should allow you to extract the numbers you are after.

As an extra note, to reduce the amount of false positives, you might want to do the following:

1. Crop the image if you are certain that certain coordinates will never contain data you are after. This should give you a smaller picture to work with.
2. It might be wise to change the image to grey scale (assuming you are working with a colour image). Colours can have a negative impact on the OCR's ability to resolve the image.

EDIT: As per your comment, given something like this:

```
+------------------------------+
|                   +---+---+  |
|                   |   |   |  |
|                   +---+---+  |
|                   +---+---+  |
|                   |   |   |  |
|                   +---+---+  |
|                   +---+---+  |
|                   |   |   |  |
|                   +---+---+  |
|                   +---+---+  |
|                   |   |   |  |
|                   +---+---+  |
+------------------------------+
```

You would crop the image so that your remove the area which does not have relevant data (the part on the left) by cropping the image, you would get something like so:

```
+-------------+
|+---+---+    |
||   |   |    | 
|+---+---+    |
|+---+---+    |
||   |   |    |
|+---+---+    |
|+---+---+    |
||   |   |    |
|+---+---+    |
|+---+---+    |
||   |   |    |
|+---+---+    |
+-------------+
```

The idea would be to run the Hough Transform so that you can get segments of the page which contain rectangles like so:

```
+---+---+    
|   |   |     
+---+---+
```

Which you would then apply the Hough Transform again and end up with two segments, and you take the left one.

Once that you have the left segment, you would then apply the OCR.

You *can* try to apply the OCR before hand, but at best, the OCR will recognize both numeric values, both written and both typed, which from what I get, is not what you are after.

Also, the extra lines which depict the rectangles might throw the OCR off track, and make it yield bad results.

Comment: its gonna be a paper so its black and white and yes the boxes would be on the right, no text would be under of over it. only boxes with distance which would vary, so its wise to crop it first and then run a ocr and separate the values?

Comment: @Hash: I have tried to augment my answer. If you have any queries please do let me know. In short, you should leave the OCR part for the end, after you have done as much pre-processing as possible (which is what the Hough Transform bit is).

Comment: as i remmber opencv supports it but no that familiar with hough transform, any recommended tutorial or example links?

Comment: @Hash: [This](https://code.google.com/r/jesse-javacv/source/browse/javacv/samples/HoughLines.java?r=c45f672721ad6f274e9ce0780ee260ed12c56d03) seems to be helpful.

Comment: @pinti: i tried this: http://vase.essex.ac.uk/software/HoughTransform/ i didnt get anything. the one u sent me couldnt get it working

Comment: @Hash: If you are having a specific problem with the Hough Transform I think it might be better if you ask another question. There is a tag for `Hough-Transform` problems, that will hopefully attract the right people. I'll try look into it later today, you can also open a bounty maybe that will help.

Comment: @pinti:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776316/hough-transform-in-java-extract-rectangles made one

Comment: @Hash: I've made a slight adjustment to your question. However, I would recommend you provide some more detail to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75854/discussion-between-hash-and-npinti).

Comment: @pinti: i checked hough

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend to combine 2 basic neural network components:

- Perceptron
- Self Organized Map (SOM)

A **perceptron** is a very simple neural network component. It takes multiple inputs and produces 1 output. You need to **train** it by feeding it both inputs and outputs. It's a self learning component.

Internally it has a collection of weight factors, which are used to calculate the output. These weight factors are perfected during training. The beautiful thing about a perceptron is that, (with a proper training) it can handle data that it has never seen before.

You can make a perceptron more powerful by arranging it **in a multi-layer network**, meaning that the output of one perceptron acts as the input of another perceptron.

**In your case you should use 10 perceptron networks, one for each numeric value (0-9).**

But in order to use perceptrons you will need an array of numeric inputs. So first you need something to convert you visual image to numeric values. **A [Self Organized Map](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/495827/filename/draft-revised.pdf) (SOM)** uses a grid of inter-connected points. The points should be attracted to the pixels of your image (See below)

[image: Self Organized Map]

The 2 components work well together. **The SOM has a fixed number of grid-nodes, and your perceptron needs a fixed number of inputs.**

Both components are really popular and are available in educational software packages such as [MATLAB](http://nl.mathworks.com/products/matlab/).

## UPDATE: 06/01/2018 - Tensor Flow

[This video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FmcHiLCwTU) demonstrates how it can be done in python using Google's TensorFlow framework. (click [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) for a written tutorial).

Comment: Neural networks are great for classifying. With multiple perceptrons what approach would you take to combine the results together? voting?
Additionally, If you need to do training anyway, why not train the OCR engine? I would think that the OCR engine could leverage knowledge that it is a character, instead of basing it solely on pixels. Or else why don't all OCR engines use straight neural networks.

Comment: @Noremac I don't really regard these drawings of characters as text. To me they seem more like drawings. On the other hand, OCR is great for parsing printed texts which usually use 1 specific font to write an entire book. If the font is always the same, then you don't need neural networks. But for drawings and pictures I expect better results from neural networks. I have heard that sometimes OCR uses vector-based recognition instead of glyphs, is that the type of OCR that you are refering to ?

Comment: An OCR engine can be trained on the "handwritten font" of the single author here. I'd be interested to see how much variation it could allow. I think it could do well with the limited vocabulary (only digits) and having been trained. A perceptron could handle variations better so I suppose it's a matter of how consistent the author is, as well as what, if any, advantages the OCR engine has by knowing it is a written character. To follow up on my other question, how would you suggest bringing the perceptron results back together to get the final classification?

Comment: @Noremac You could simply make each network result in a single output node, with a floating point value [0.0 - 1.0] (i.e. 0.0 = absolutely no match and 1.0 = a perfect match.) Then just check which of the 10 networks has the best score.

Answer (score 8):

Neural networks is a typical approach for this kind of problems.

In this scenario, you can consider each handwritten number a matrix of pixels. You may get better results if you train the neural network with images of the same size as the image you want to recognize.

You can train the neural network with different images of handwritten numbers. Once trained, if you pass the image of the handwritten number to identify, it will return the most similar number.

Of course, the quality of training images is a key factor to get good results.

Comment: I agree that a matrix of pixels is sufficient to pass it to a neural network (e.g. a perceptron network). But if the matrix size is variable (which I guess it is not here) or if you want to limit the number of inputs for your perceptrons, then it's better to use a SOM (as explained in my answer).

Answer (score 5):

In most image processing problems you want to look to leverage as much information you have as possible. Given the image there are assumptions we can make (and possibly more):

1. The boxes around the numbers are consistent.
2. The number on the right is always 8 (or known ahead of time)
3. The number on the left is always a number
4. The number on the left is always handwriting and written by the same person

Then we can simplify the problem using those assumptions:

1. You can use a simpler approach to find the numbers (template matching). When you have the coordinates of the match you can create a sub image and subtract out the template and be left with only the numbers you want to give to the OCR engine. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html .
2. If you know what numbers to expect, then you can get those from another source and not risk OCR errors. You could even include the 8 as part of the template.
3. You can greatly reduce the vocabulary (possible OCR results), based on this, increasing the OCR engine's accuracy. There is a whitelist setting for TesseractOCR to do this (see https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recognize_only_digits?).
4. Handwriting is much harder for an OCR engine to recognize (They are meant for printed fonts). However, you can train the OCR engine to recognize the author's "font". (see http://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/)

The gist though is to use any assumptions that you can to reduce the problem into smaller, simpler sub problems. Then look to see what tools are available to solve each of those sub problems individually.

Assumptions are hard to make as well if you have to start worrying about the real world, like if these will be scanned it, you'll need to consider skew or rotation of the "template" or the numbers.

Comment: 8 would change. lets say i isolate the lines and 8 and im left with the numbers on the left (handwritten text) then if i train the ocr that would work? ya same person would be writting the marks

Comment: How well it works really depends on how consistent the author is. I think this is your best shot though with a consistent author. Handwriting recognition is a whole separate field from OCR to account for the possible variations. OCR is more rigid and doesn't allow for as much variation.

Comment: then what would be recommended to identify the numbers?

Comment: Are you asking about the handwritten numbers? If so, there's not as much available specifically for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249501/is-there-a-viable-handwriting-recognition-library-program

Comment: ya to train to identify the numbers maybe

Answer (score 1):

Give it up. Really. I as a human can not say for sure if the third letter is a '1' or a '7'. Humans are better in deciphering, so a computer will fail for this.
'1' and '7' is only one problematic case, '8' and '6', '3' and '9' are also hard to decipher/distinguish. Your error quote will be >10%.
If all the handwriting is from the same person you could try to train an OCR for that, but even in this case you will still have about ~3% errors. It might be that your use case is special, but this number of errors usually prohibits any kind of automated processing.
I would look into Mechanical Turk if I really have to automate this.

Comment: @amit Humans will always be better than computers doing OCR. If humans can not read a piece of text, there is no text.

Comment: No. There was an article some years ago, where they took numbers, and added random noise to the pictures. At a certain point of noise - humans could not correctly read the numbers anymore, but computers could correctly identify the original digit.

Comment: @RobAu I read it so long ago I really don't remember even who the author was or where it got published. Will give it a shot, but don't hold your breath. :|

Comment: @tobltobs if you are correct, then how does your mail reach your house ? The sorting of mail in post offices is almost entirely done by computers these days.

Comment: @bvdb is referring to [Reading handwritten digits: a ZIP code recognition system](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=144441&tag=1)

Comment: @amit You get a check with an unreadable amount. It could be a '100' or maybe a '700'. Your OCR tool says it is an '700'. Would you pay 700? And what do you do if the next person only gives you 100 for the check? When a computer tells you that it is a 700 he just says, that that is the number with the highest probability. But humans have kind of common agreement what a number has to look like. The current OCR systems a far away form being able to handle this.

Comment: @bvdb By handling the cases where the OCR system fails manually. http://img.deseretnews.com/images/article/midres/1270164/1270164.jpg

Comment: @tobltobs back in [1957, Chow](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5222035&tag=1) has already proposed to handle it by adding a reject option. A long way has passed since then, and recent work is achieving great results in getting very accurate results while rejecting a small portion of noisy data.

Comment: @tobltobs If it's really unreadable, then that doesn't mean that the program has failed. That's what `UserException`s are for. Just "Return to sender". Unreadable text can't be sorted by humans neither.

Comment: I take it, you won't be the first google-car passenger :). just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load the image, convert to grayscale, then Otsu's threshold to get a 1-channel binary image with pixels ranging from `[0...255]`.
2. **Detect horizontal and vertical lines.** Create horizontal and vertical [structuring elements](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) then draw lines onto a mask by performing [morphological operations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html).
3. **Remove horizontal and vertical lines.** Combine horizontal and vertical masks using a [bitwise_or](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-or) operation then remove the lines using a [bitwise_and](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) operation.
4. **Perform OCR.** Apply a slight [Gaussian blur](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering) then OCR using [Pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/).

---

Here's a visualization of each step:

Input image `->` Binary image `->` Horizontal mask `->` Vertical mask

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Combined masks `->` Result `->` Applied slight blur

[image]
[image]
[image]

Result from OCR

```
38
18
78
```

I implemented it with Python but you can adapt a similar approach using Java

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Detect horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,1))
horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=1)

# Detect vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,25))
vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=1)

# Remove horizontal and vertical lines
lines = cv2.bitwise_or(horizontal, vertical)
result = cv2.bitwise_not(image, image, mask=lines)

# Perform OCR with Pytesseract
result = cv2.GaussianBlur(result, (3,3), 0)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)

# Display
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('horizontal', horizontal)
cv2.imshow('vertical', vertical)
cv2.imshow('lines', lines)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```