# Hough transform in Java extract rectangles

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, ocr, hough-transform

I tried this example [Hough Transform](http://vase.essex.ac.uk/software/HoughTransform/).

But I didn't get any results after making an example with original image.

I'm currently wanting to make it work for my application where I'm trying to extract the boxes out and use OCR and get the numbers of this.

[image]

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745704/recognize-a-number-from-an-image) question for more information.

So, I could then add them all up. It's from a `paper.png`, whose the right side is cropped.

Comment: try saving it as a .jpg and see if that helps

Comment: You don't need to "remove the boxes"; for each digit you need to crop to contain *only* the contents of the box. You can use a hough transform to find the places in the image where the most lines intersect, ie. at the corners of the boxes. Once you have the corner coordinates, cropping is easy.

Comment: @GKitteridge doesnt work

Comment: @beerbajay yes but im not sure how to do it, i tried example didnt work.

Comment: You apply an edge filter, do the hough on vertical and horizontal lines, find the local maxima. There are your corner points...

Comment: im nt sure on how to do hough, thats why tried example but no results