# Getting handwritten text from images

Tags: java, image, ocr, eclipse-mars

How to extract handwritten text from images, like bank form images, in Java?
I tried to using Tesseract, OCR, GOCR but didn't working for me. Are there any other ways to extract handwritten text from images in Java which works at least 80-90%?

Answer (score 0):

[Question with links to libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249501/is-there-a-viable-handwriting-recognition-library-program)

I don't think JAVA natively supports this function, so you gotta use libraries.
There was a question which asked for working libraries and the general consent was: you won't get a 80-90% working recognition in a free and open source library.

Anyway, you can try [this](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/), as it is a wrapper for Tesseract.